# Using d3.js to Draw a dynamic polygon around selected objects in a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

Given below is my code sample, I have tried using css stroke & outline but both are not meeting my requirements i.e, applying stroke to the 'g' will add stroke to all the elements in it, but it will be all around every elements (image 1). I am looking for a single border that is going around the elements. So I tried using css 'outline' to the 'g' tag which results in a rectangle border, again not around the objects collectively (image 2).

Image 1 (using css 'stroke')

[image]

Image 2 (using css 'outline' to the 'g')

[image]

Image 3 (This is what I am trying to achieve)

[image]

```
<g class="selected-group" data-id="24907">
   <polygon fill="#F9E794" points="3476.813,1307.591 3476.813,1308.81 3476.813,1357.5 3425.223,1357.5 3425.223,1308.81 3425.223,1307.591" class="selected" data-id="24907"></polygon>
   <polygon fill="#F9E794" points="3425.223,1307.591 3425.223,1308.81 3425.223,1357.5 3425.223,1404.68 3376.153,1404.68 3376.153,1357.5 3376.153,1307.591" class="selected" data-id="974937"></polygon>
</g>
```

Appreciate any support on this. ThankYou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this kind of what you're looking for? This example is not a generalized solution. You need to perform a boolean union of the geometry and render that on top of the other polygons.

```js
// assumes clockwise point ordering
var blocks = [
  ['10,10', '230,10', '230,490', '10,490'],
  ['230,10', '490,10', '490,230', '230,230']
];

var selection = blocks[0];
selection.splice(
  selection.indexOf(blocks[1][0]), 1, blocks[1]
);

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('.area-box')
  .data(blocks)
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('class', 'area-box')
  .attr('points', function (d) { return d.join(' ') });

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('.bounding-box')
  .data([selection])
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .attr('class', 'bounding-box')
  .attr('points', function (d) { return d.join(' ') });
```

```css
.area-box {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: darkgray;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
.bounding-box {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.bounding-box:hover {
  fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.js"></script>
<svg width='500' height='500' viewBox='0 0 1200 1200'></svg>
```

Comment: so basically, u r suggessting to create a bounding polygon using the coordinates from the selected elements?

Comment: Pretty much. Groups will always be quadrilaterals so you'll need composition rather than aggregation.